# C - what is array name when not converted to pointer of its type?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, type-conversion

So for a while I was confused about array names and pointers.

We declare `int a[10];`
And somewhere down the road also have `a` and `&a`.

So I get how the syntax works. `a` is the array name. When it is not used as an operand for `sizeof` `&`, etc., it will be converted or "decayed" so it returns a pointer to integer holding the address of the first element of the array.

If the array name is used as an operand for  `sizeof` or `&`, its type is `int (*)[10]`. So I guess the type is different because that "decay" does not happen.

But I still do not understand how `&a` works. My understanding is that it is giving me the address of `whatever it was before the "decay" happened`.. So before the "decay" to pointer happened, then what is it and how does the compiler work with the "original" to evaluate `&a`?

In comparison, if we declare `int *p;`
and later have `&p` and `p` somewhere in the code...

In this case the pointer to integer `p` is given a separate pointer cell with its address and the value at that address will be whatever address we assign to it (or the garbage value at that address pre-assignment).

`a` does not get assigned a separate pointer cell in memory when it is declared `int a[10]`. I heard it is identified with an offset on the register `%ebp`. Then what is happening with the compiler when it evaluates `&a`? The "decay" to a pointer to integer is not happening, there was no separate "pointer" in the first place. Then what does the compiler identify `a` as and what does it do when it sees that unary `&` operator is using the array name as an operand?

Comment: That first code block only compiles in C because C treats all pointer types as compatible and the address of an array is the same as the address of the first element. In C++ it is a pointer type mismatch.

Comment: i will remove the c++ tag

Comment: @CruzJean `a == &a` is also a pointer type mismatch in C.

Comment: @chux Well ya, but as far as I'm aware C just emits a warning at best. Though I might just be used to old versions of C compilers.

Comment: @CruzJean I will edit that part as well. I didn't really mean an actual block of code. Just an illustration of what I was thinking.

Comment: Here's another example to consider:  If you have `int b[20][10]`, and for instance you pass `b` as a function argument, it decays to type `int (*)[10]`.  This makes sense, since `b[0]` has type `int [10]`, so `&b[0]` has type `int (*)[10]`.  And of course, `&b` has type `int (*)[20][10]`.

Comment: Re “If the array name is used as an operand for `sizeof` or `&`, its type is `int (*)[10]`”: No, if `a` is used as an operand for `sizeof` or `&`, its type is `int [10]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
int a[10];
```

the object `a` is of type `int[10]`. The *expression* `a`, in most but not all contexts, "decays" to a pointer expression; the expression yields a value of type `int*`, equivalent to `&a[0]`.

> But I still do not understand how `&a` works. My understanding is that it is giving me the address of *whatever it was before the "decay" happened*.. So before the "decay" to pointer happened, then what is it and how does the compiler work with the "original" to evaluate `&a`?

That's not quite correct. In `&a`, the decay doesn't happen at all. `a` is of type "array of 10 `int`" (`int[10]`), so `&a` is of type "pointer to array of 10 `int`" (`int(*)[10]`).

There's nothing special about this. For any name `foo` of type `some_type`, the expression `&foo` is of type "pointer to `some_type`". (What's confusing about it is that this is one of the rare cases where an array name *doesn't* behave strangely.)

It's best to think of the words "array" and "pointer" as adjectives rather than nouns.  Thus we can have an array object, an array expression, an array type, and so forth -- but just "an array" is ambiguous.

This:

```
int a[10];
```

defines an array object named `a` (and allocates `4 * sizeof (int)` bytes to hold it). No pointer object is created. You can create a pointer *value* by taking the address of the object, or of any element of it. This is no different than objects of any other type. Defining an object of type `some_type` doesn't create an object of type `some_type*`, but you can create a value of type `some_type*` by computing the address of the object.

Answer (score 1):

> Then what does the compiler identify a as and what does it do when it
>   sees that unary & operator is using the array name as an operand?

The compiler identifies `a` as a 10-element integer array, and when it sees the `&` operator, it returns the address of that array.

Just like it would see `int i = 3;` as an integer, and `&i` as the address of that integer.

Comment: i was over-thinking this problem a little bit.. and was actually getting to the same `int x = 5;` example to think about `int a[10];`

Comment: More than a little bit, it seems. :) Sometimes it helps to back away from the trees and try and see the forest.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning taking the address of an array: an array is an object in and of itself, so it has both a size and an address (though taking its address is seldom useful).

The conversion of an array to a pointer to its first element is a form of type coercion. It only happens if the alternative would be a compile error.

For instance, you can't compare an array to a pointer, so the array (implicitly) is coerced (cast) to an `int*` (to its first element) and then the pointer types are compared. In C you can compare any pointer types. C just doesn't care (though it will likely emit a warning).

This is actually comparing `int*` to `int(*)[10]` as far as types are concerned, as you said. These will necessary have the same address (regardless of typing) because arrays hold their data directly. So the address of an array will always be the address of its first element.

However, it's not an error to get the size of an array, so `sizeof(a)` gets the size of the entire array, as no coercion is needed to make this legal. So this is the same as `sizeof(int[10])`.

Your other case `sizeof(&a)` is really `sizeof(int(*)[10])` as you said.

Comment: sorry I guess my code blocks were misleading. I was not really asking about `a == &a` would compile? But what the compiler was doing when it encounters `&a`

Comment: `sizeof(++a)` (which is what I assume you mean), is an error, since `a` is not an l-value

Comment: @MarkBenningfield No, I meant `sizeof(+a)` it forces an array to pointer conversion. It's classically called the decay operator in this context.

Comment: Well, `+a` would result in an illegal operand error in C.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Ah, just tested it and you're correct. I was thinking of C++. I'll remove that from the answer.

Comment: @namesake22 I think I've edited the answer to cover that better now - an array is an object, so it has both a size and an address.

Comment: would it be possible for you to add a bit more about how the compiler knows where to look in the memory when it sees the array name? (since it's not like int *p where the pointer has both an address location accessible via &p and access the value stored there via p?)

Comment: @namesake22 Well think of it this way: on a 64-bit platform, a pointer is likely 8 bytes. Those bytes can be accessed individually, but you've told the compiler to treat them collectively as one entity. Sort of like an array (in a very loose sense).

Comment: An array is not unique in having a size and an address, though. All variables of a complete type in C have a size and an address.

Comment: Re “The conversion … only happens if the alternative would be a compile error.”: That is not the rule for conversion of an array to a pointer to its first element. As an example, there is no inherent reason the comma expression could not retain the array type, the same way the parentheses expression does, but an array in a comma expression will be converted to a pointer to its first element. The ternary expression is similar; `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(0 ? a : a));` will print the size of the pointer, not the array.

Comment: Re “ In C you can compare any pointer types. C just doesn't care (though it will likely emit a warning).”: C does care; comparing incompatible pointer types is a constraint violation (C 2018 6.5.9 2), so a conforming C implementation **must** (not “likely”) issue a diagnostic. While an implementation may then extend C by continuing to translate the program, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. The result of the comparison may not be what you expect. Pointers to different things could compare equal, or a pointer to an array could compare unequal to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Re “These will necessary have the same address (regardless of typing) because arrays hold their data directly. So the address of an array will always be the address of its first element.”: While the address of an array and the address of its first element must point to the same byte in some sense, the standard does not require that they compare equal or that they have the same representation. A proper way to convert them would be to convert them both to `char *` and then compare them. But if the comparison is made directly, and accepted by the compiler, the standard does not define the result.